# Compute Total Tip and Tax for Restaurant Bill

Tags: java

I need to use two methods. One is `getMealCharge()` and needs to return a `mealCharge` and no argument. The second is `computeAndPrintTotalBill()` and needs to do calculation in that method.

My question is- when I get the user input from first method, how do I get that number to apply to the second method so it can calculate.

If I put everything on the first method, it will work. But, for some reasons in the second method it won't show up. If anyone can please help me finding what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ComputeTip{ 

   final double taxRate = 0.0725;
   final double tipRate = 0.15; 
   double mealCharge;
   double tax;
   double tip;
   double total;

   public double getMealCharge(){

      System.out.println("Enter meal charge: ");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
      mealCharge = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
      return mealCharge;
   }

   public void computeAndPrintTotalBill(double getMealCharge, double mealCharge){

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      tax = mealCharge * taxRate;
      tip = mealCharge * tipRate;
      total = mealCharge + tax + tip;

      Test.println("charge: " + mealCharge);
      Test.println("tax: " + tax);
      Test.println("tip: " + tip);
      Test.println("total: " + total);   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the parameters wrong.
Try this:

```
public void computeAndPrintTotalBill(){
    double mealCharge = getMealCharge();
    tax = mealCharge * taxRate;
    tip = mealCharge * tipRate;
    total = mealCharge + tax + tip;
    Test.println("charge: " + mealCharge);
    Test.println("tax: " + tax);
    Test.println("tip: " + tip);
    Test.println("total: " + total);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am now able to get user input to the second method.

Comment: Hi @powermedia24 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use only computeAndPrintTotalBill method to get your work done by modifying your methods and variable as below:

```
final static double taxRate = 0.0725;
final static double tipRate = 0.15;

public static void computeAndPrintTotalBill(double mealCharge) {

double tax= mealCharge * taxRate;
double tip = mealCharge * tipRate;
double total= mealCharge + tax + tip;

    System.out.println("charge: " + mealCharge);
    System.out.println("tax: " + tax);
    System.out.println("tip: " + tip);
    System.out.println("total: " + total);
}
public static void main(String...args){

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
Double mealCharge = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
computeAndPrintTotalBill(mealCharge);

}
```

OUTPUT:

> ```
> 21.5
> charge: 21.5
> tax: 1.5587499999999999
> tip: 3.225
> total: 26.28375
> ```

Note: You can also do

```
 ComputeTip computeTip = new ComputeTip();
 double mealCharge = computeTip.getMealCharge();
 computeTip.computeAndPrintTotalBill(mealCharge);
```

In your original program (Need to remove `double getMealCharge` from your method signature). This also works fine.